# Multiline Text Truncation Issue

Tags: jquery, html, scalability, markup, truncate

I currently have a snippet of jQuery that is successfully truncating my text when the child string is larger then the parent container (see below).

```
var initial = $('.js-text').text();
$('.js-text').text(initial);
while($('.js-text').outerHeight() > $('.js-text-truncator').height()) {
  $('.js-text').text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
  });
}
```

I have used the semantics I have as I had planned to use this little jQuery component in more than one place in existing markup like so:

```
<div class="existing-first-div-container js-text-truncator">
  <p class="existing-first-string js-text">The quick brown fox</p>
</div>
<div class="existing-second-div-container js-text-truncator">
  <p class="existing-second-string js-text"> jumped over the lazy red dog.</p>
</div>
```

Kudos if you've read this far and already guessed my problem btw...

So the problem is that my jQuery is storing the text, but it's storing *all* the text. So both of these existing divs are being truncated, but both wind up reading "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy red dog." rather than the first reading "The quick brown fox" and the second reading " jumped over the lazy red dog."

Is it possible to use my js-text-truncator as an extension to my markup in the way that I intend, without storing all truncated text instances at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` clearly states

> Get the **combined** text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

Once you have your set of elements with `.js-text`, do a `.each` on them, and get, truncate and set the `.text` separately.

If you want it to re-run when the window re-sizes, I advise you to do it through a timeout (so the code runs once after the window stopped being resized for at least 400ms). Without this workaround it tends to weigh quite heavy on performance.

```
var resizeTimeout = false;
$(window).resize(onWindowResize); // bind resize event.

trimAllText(); //run once at start.

function onWindowResize() {
    if(resizeTimeout){
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    }
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(e){ 
        resizeTimeout = false; 

        // this is code that is ran at the "end" of a resize.
        trimAllText();
    }, 400);
}

function trimAllText(){
  var initialElements = $('.js-text');
  initialElements.each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    while(elem.outerHeight() > elem.closest('.js-text-truncator').height()) {
      elem.text(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this truncates the two. I might not have given enough detail though... This doesn't store or add/remove text when the browser window is adjusted: http://jsfiddle.net/ts7bs9q3/

Comment: If you want it on the window resize, you can just bind the same function to .resize :) Give me a moment to add it to the answer.

Comment: Hi Again,
Your first solution was successfully trimming the text on the fly without the 400ms delay. But it still isn't adding text back if you resize the browser larger. I suspect this is because we're not storing each text initially? I'll tick your answer as you have technically answered my question. But if you've got any more ideas that'd be awesome ;)

Comment: Ah right I missed the idea of re-adding it! You can use an attribute to store the original text within the markup, such as `data-init="put initial text here"`, before you replace it the first time. Alternatively you could compute an array of objects that hold the element and the initial text. `var inits = [{elem = $('some$obj'), text = "$('some$obj').text()"}, ...]`